# How can I mitigate my energy monitor losing its accumulated totals?

Tags: esp32, home-assistant, esphome

I recently added a power monitor to our homelab, flashed it with ESPHome and configured some mini-graph-cards to visualise power and energy use. Everything looked good, until I started to see frequent, though irregular resets.

[image: 3 day and 2 hour Sonoff power measure stack]

Both the daily and total values reset at the same time, plus the daily total resets every midnight, as expected.

I'm using the standard `sensor:` block from [Sonoff-POW-Elite-20a](https://devices.esphome.io/devices/Sonoff-POW-Elite-20a), so for *Total Daily Energy*, it's using:

```
- platform: total_daily_energy
  name: $friendly_name Total Daily Energy
  power_id: w_sensor
  filters:
    - multiply: 0.001
  unit_of_measurement: kWh
```

With no explicit `restore: false` I would expect that totals to be restored after a reset (default being `true`) and carry on from where they left off, but that doesn't seem to be the case.

While I could post process the data work out new daily totals (interpolating the missing data and extrapolating from there) it would be good to know if there were any way to do this at source.

I see there is a `platform:kalman_combinator`, to combine multiple sensors into a single more accurate sensor, but I can't see a kalman filter to do the same for a time series, nor can I see how I would store history if I did.

So, how can I mitigate a device resetting itself like this, losing it's accumulated totals.

Comment: If it is indeed doing unexpected resets, it maybe more predictable for you to have an explicit restore: false .  
And then, of course, you have to detect that there was a reset. Is there a session id of some sort that you can use or do you have to detect it because the kWh started back from near zero ?